# Compact Subspace of Sorgenfrey line

Tags: general-topology

Let $K$ be a compact subspace of the Sorgenfrey line $\mathbb R_l$ (half open interval topology). How can I prove that $K$ is at most countable?

Answer (score 2):

If $K$ is a compact subspace of $\mathbb{R}_l$, then its topology is the same as the subspace topology of plain $\mathbb{R}$ since a compact topology cannot be strictly finer than a Hausdorff topology. Let $x ∈ K$. $x ∉ \overline{(-∞, x) ∩ K}$ in both topologies, so there is $y_x < x$ such that $(y_x, x) ∩ K = ∅$. So $\{(y_x, x): x ∈ K\}$ is a collection of disjoint nonempty open sets, which cannot be uncountable since $\mathbb{R}_l$ is separable.